# If std::addressof is a readable version of &. What is a readable version of *&?

Tags: c++, c++11, address-operator

`*&x`

Using c++11, we can write as

`* std::addressof(x)`

However, is there more readable version of this expression?

```
constexpr uint64_t lil_endian = 0x65'6e'64'69'61'6e; 
    // a.k.a. Clockwise-Rotated Endian which allocates like
    // char[8] = { n,a,i,d,n,e,\0,\0 }

constexpr auto& arr = 
    reinterpret_cast<const std::array<char,8> &>
        (*std::addressof(lil_endian) );

int main()
{
    const auto str = std::string(arr.crbegin()+2, arr.crend() );

    std::cout << str << '\n'
              << str.size() << '\n' << '\n';
    for (const auto ch : str) {
        std::cout << ch << " : " << std::hex << (unsigned int) ch << '\n';
    }

}


endian
6

e : 65
n : 6e
d : 64
i : 69
a : 61
n : 6e
```

[godbolt.org/g/9StHsE](https://gcc.godbolt.org/g/9StHsE)

[wandbox.org/permlink/ZzQ38IlDficO5UOi](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZzQ38IlDficO5UOi)

Comment: Accessing `lil_endian` through `arr` is undefined behavior. Also, what're you trying to do? `*&x` for "normal types" is a noop

Comment: @Barry I don't know how to explain this but try to replace `*&x` with `x` on that godbolt link above.

Comment: & and addressof are are not equal in general

Comment: You find `std::addressof` *more* readable?

Comment: @sandthorn Your godbolt link produces the exact same assembly using `lil_endian`, `*&lil_endian`, or `*std::addressof(lil_endian)`.

Comment: @miles-budnek Thanks. Now I can compile those.

Answer (score 19):

> `* std::addressof(x)`
>
> However, is there more readable version of this expression?

`x`

Comment: Not totaly equivalent though with pathologic classes.

Comment: I can not just replace `*std::addressof(lil_endian)` with `lil_endian` on the example code above. You can try for yourself on the godbolt link.

Comment: @sandthorn: that's a good thing, because what you have is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @vittorio-romeo You mean I can not write `reinterpret_cast<const std::array<char,8> &>` without depending on undefined behavior?

Comment: @sandthorn: yes - `reinterpret_cast` cannot be valid of a well-formed *constant expression*.

Comment: @vittorio-romeo Well, remove constexpr and change into `const auto& arr = reinterpret_cast<const std::array<char,8> &>(lil_endian);` doesn't compile either. [godbolt.org/g/ZgVKQu] (https://gcc.godbolt.org/g/ZgVKQu)

Comment: @sandthorn: it does, you just misspelled `lil_endian`. You still have undefined behavior as you're breaking the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @vittorio-romeo Ah, okey. my bad. thanks. But where I can read more on "strick aliasing rule" ?

Comment: @vittorio-romeo One more thing, How do I force the compiler to report this as 'undefined behavior' when compiling?

Comment: @sandthorn It is undefined behaviour with no diagnostic required, because detecting what is defined and not at runtime is (in the general case) Halt-hard.

Comment: @sandthorn: unfortunately, you cannot reliably do so.

Comment: @Yakk Do you mean `const auto& arr = reinterpret_cast<const std::array<char,8> &>(lil_endian);` is considered as defined on compile time but undefined in runtime?

Answer (score 11):

Vittorio Romeo give you the answer to the second question.

The first supposition is wrong: "Is `addressof` the readable version of `&`". `addressof` is used to get the address of an object even if its class type has an overloaded `operator &`.

Comment: @remy-lebeau This means that `std::addressof` is now preferred to `&` when address is needed?

Comment: @sandthorn: Only when the object's type has an overridden `operator&` that doesn't return the object's true address.  This is not uncommon in non-STL smart pointer classes, for instance.

Comment: @sandthron Many libraries use `addressof` indeed, even the STL (see also std::pointer_traits::pointer_to). I don't. I prefer to reject any library where `operator &` is overloaded. If such a mistake (overloading this operator) has been done, you can expect a lot more mistake. To take decision, you need clear indicator: `operator &` overloaded => library rejected.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you're trying to do and why you use `constexpr`.

But there are a couple of issues with your code:

- `reinterpret_cast` is [not allowed](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.15) in a constant expression.
- aliasing `uint64_t` with a `std::array` is [not allowed](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prop#basic.lval-11).

You *can*, however, work around both of these by aliasing using a `const char*` in a non-`constexpr` context. So the following is legal:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr uint64_t lil_endian = 0x65'6e'64'69'61'6e; 

int main()
{
    auto arr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&lil_endian);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(lil_endian); ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " : " << std::hex << (unsigned int) arr[i] << '\n';
    }

}
```

Incidentally also the need for `*&` disappears.

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/g/aEmAsu)

**== EDIT ==**

If you just need to get a hold of the *size* of the variable in a generic way, just use `sizeof` in a function template. For example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

constexpr uint64_t lil_endian = 0x65'6e'64'69'61'6e; 
constexpr uint32_t lil_endian32 = 0x65'6e'64'69;

template<typename T>
void printIt(const T& it)
{
    auto arr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&it);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(it); ++i) {
        putchar(arr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printIt(lil_endian);
    printIt(lil_endian32);
}
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/g/uf7WWX)

Comment: (1) constexpr : now I know that reinterpret is not allowed (2)  I'm trying to make `arr` have the size of `lil_endian` that's all. However I wonder if `reinterpret_cast<const char*>` is "legal". How about `auto& arr = reinterpret_cast<char (&) [8]>(lil_endian);` ? Are we also accessing char right?

Comment: Original question are now well answered by many. Perhaps I should make this "strict alias" topic as another question. Anyway, thanks you @rustyx for the function template.